# Android API level compatibility with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In the following development environment

> Windows 10
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview
>
> Version 15.6.0 Preview 6.0
>
> VisualStudio.15.Preview/15.6.0-pre.6.0+27421.1
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02558
>
> Xamarin   4.9.0.748 (04061cef1)
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   8.2.0.15 (HEAD/22d97e153)

I have a Xamarin.Forms application, with the following Android version settings:

> Android Target Framework: 7.1 (Nougat) API level 25
>
> Minimum Android version: Use Compile using SDK version
>
> Target Android version: Use Compile using SDK version

I start the Debug Configuration in Visual Studio, using as debug target two different smartphones connected through USB; they are equipped with earlier Android Versions than 7.1 (one is 6 API 23, the other is 4.1 API level 16).

Based on what I read in the documentation, I shouldn't be able to run my app in these devices, but it does run indeed. I was at least expecting a "minimum version" error.

My questions are:

1) Is this behavior expected?

2) How does Xamarin.Forms achieve this result?

3) Should I expect the same outcome with the release version published in the store or is it only a bonus offered when debugging in the IDE?

My guess is that as long as I don't make any specific platform calls but stick with the Xamarin.Forms abstraction, the application will run in all the Android versions supported by Xamarin.Forms (>= Android 4.0.3 - API 15), but I couldn't find a confirmation.